# python3 django gitignore project/bin and project/include?

Tags: django, git, python-3.x, gitignore

I have a django project called sibs. I'm currently upgrading it to use python3. I noticed that there is a bin and include folder inside my projects folder (~/projects/sibs/sibs) where all the settings and url_confs go.

Should these be in the gitignore? I looked at some examples and they weren't but I find it hard to believe that the bin should be tracked by git. I just want to double check. I assume these will be regenerated upon run-time.

EDIT
My folder hierarchy is like so (I'm using virtualenvwrapper):

```
~
   | projects
       | sibs
           | sibs
               | settings.py
               | urls.py
               | bin
               | include
           manage.py
   | envs
       | sibs
           | *environment-stuff*
```

Answer (score 0):

Those folders aren't part of or generated by a typical Django project or application so you should be able to safely add them to your **.gitignore**.

**Edit:** It just dawned on me, are you trying to work within a **virtual environment** folder? Because `bin` and `include` are definitely folders inside of one:
[image]

If your virtual environment is named the same as an application in your Django project, and you have Django files in your virtual environment folder, please restructure your project's files so that's not the case! Ideally you'll have a folder structure that looks something like this (I like to flatten out my Django project structures by including a period at the end of the `startproject` command):

```
~/R/djangotest $> python3 -m venv venv
~/R/djangotest $> source venv/bin/activate
(venv) ~/R/djangotest $> pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-1.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from django)
  Using cached pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, django
Successfully installed django-1.11.5 pytz-2017.2
(venv) ~/R/djangotest $> django-admin startproject djangotest .
(venv) ~/R/djangotest $>
```

[image]

Once you've done that, you most certainly can add the virtual environment directory to .gitignore, they're disposable so long as you keep your **requirements.txt** file up-to-date with your list of dependencies.

Comment: I just updated my question. I'm not working inside a virtual environment. I have the project and the environment clearly separated out (So people cloning the project can have their own independant virtualenv. So the bin, include, lib are not from the environment... unless the folders underwent some spontaneous quantum physics and appeared in my project lol.

As for the first part, I didn't test it because I ended scrapping the branch and not upgrading to Python 3

Comment: Vanilla django doesn't create bin or include inside the project app path. What's in there specifically? These are either the result of unintended copying or part of a customized startproject template.